# How to migrate Access DB to PostgreSQL server

Tags: postgresql

I know it can be quite odd question, but I was wondering if there's a tool that allows me to convert an Access DB to PostgreSQL with the table structure... I've found some third-party tools as dBForce that import data but not the structure.

Thanks

Comment: This may not help, if you know a little .NET this is a relatively small task.  I wrote a similar program going from Access to Oracle.  I believe that Alteryx will do something like this, so maybe one of the open source tools similar to it (Knime) might work?

Comment: Also, EXCELLENT idea to migrate an Access DB to a dedicated database...

Comment: ok but how do I respect table relationships between tables?